Failed to load application context for ITs when upgraded spring to 6.1 version
Hi I recently upgraded my spring-boot-dependencies version from 3.1.11 to 3.2.5 when running the ITs of the existing project they are failing with "Fail to load application context error", the base error which is causing
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.NoSuchJobException: No job configuration with the name [downloadStatementFiles] was registered
this is the complete stack trace :
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [MergedContextConfiguration@54648a05 testClass = BatchPostProcessingIT, locations = [], classes = [TestConfig, test.batch.config.TestMockedContextConfiguration], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = ["NonWebsphere", "MockedHazelcast", "MockedProperties"], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = [], contextCustomizers = [], contextLoader = org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader, parent = null]
  at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180)
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:142)
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:98)
  at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
  at FlakyTestRetryRunner.runChild(FlakyTestRetryRunner.java:58)
  at FlakyTestRetryRunner.runChild(FlakyTestRetryRunner.java:22)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
  FlakyTestRetryRunner.run(FlakyTestRetryRunner.java:42)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobController' defined in file [JobController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'simpleJobService' defined in file [SimpleJobService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 5: Error creating bean with name 'downloadStatementFileJobLauncher' defined in file [DownloadStatementFileJobLauncher.class]: Failed to instantiate [DownloadStatementFileJobLauncher]: Constructor threw exception
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1192)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:221)
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:110)
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:212)
  at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225)
  at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152)
  ... 12 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleJobService' defined in file [SimpleJobService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 5: Error creating bean with name 'downloadStatementFileJobLauncher' defined in file [DownloadStatementFileJobLauncher.class]: Failed to instantiate [DownloadStatementFileJobLauncher]: Constructor threw exception
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1192)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782)
  ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'downloadStatementFileJobLauncher' defined in file [batch/DownloadStatementFileJobLauncher.class]: Failed to instantiate [batch.DownloadStatementFileJobLauncher]: Constructor threw exception
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:318)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:306)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1192)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1689)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1653)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeanCollection(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1543)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1511)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1392)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782)
  ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [batch.DownloadStatementFileJobLauncher]: Constructor threw exception
  at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:221)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:111)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:315)
  ... 61 more
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.NoSuchJobException: No job configuration with the name [downloadStatementFiles] was registered
  at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry.getJob(MapJobRegistry.java:68)
  at batch.DownloadStatementFileJobLauncher.<init>(DownloadStatementFileJobLauncher.java:34)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
  at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:208)
  ... 63 more

kindly give suggestion how can I move past this
